# Powershell tail parameter in powershell 2.0

Tags: powershell

I have prepared a PowerShell script in PS 3.0 and when I am executing it in PS 2.0 I am getting an error saying "A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts the argument -tail".

The same command is being executed well in PS 3.0. Below is my command.

```
get-content '\\mtrlpqdc2c4-035\D$\HPBSM\log\odb\jvm_statistics.log' -Tail 1
```

Is there any other parameter that I can use instead of  "-Tail"

Comment: I have tried "select -last 1". For this also I got the same output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `Get-Content` did not add the `Tail` parameter until v3.

A fast workaround:

```
(Get-Content -Path $path)[-1]
```

---

I believe `Tail` does not gather the content of the entire file and select `n` lines like my workaround does, so this method will be significantly slower on a large enough file unless you implement your own method of getting the end of a file.

Comment: This Worked like a Charm.